# Access client side variable on the server side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an app which has a lot of client side javascript handling for navigation around a responsive app (which ultimately consists of one gigantic form).

Basically, as the user progresses through the form (i.e. presses a button which is handled client side in javascript) I need to store the timestamp in which the user presses the button.

I'm storing the timestamp in JavaScript variables when the button event is triggered.

Now, when the user presses the submit button on the form and it sends the POST request to the server, I need to send the values of these variables.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: asp runs on the server, js runs on the server. if you want to access something in JS from the server, you'd need to have JS send it back to the server via ajax.

Comment: I think you meant "js runs on the *client*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hidden input to store the `DateTime` value and update the value in your buttons click event. Ideally, generate this input based on a property in your view model, otherwise, add an additional parameter to you post method to accept the date.  For example

Option 1: Add additional property to your view model e.g. `public DateTime UserDate { get; set; }` and in the view

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserDate)
```

and in the script, update its value

```
$('#UserDate').val((new Date()).toUTCString());
```

Option 2: Without additional view model property

```
<input type="hidden" id="UserDate" name="UserDate" />
```

and in the post method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourMethod(YourModel model, DateTime userDate)
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of Hidden field should solve your issue. update the hidden field in JS with the time you want and access that in server side

Comment: Any chance you could provide a coding example of passing say a basic value? Cheers

Comment: This doesn't appear to be MVC

Comment: Oh if so please check the following link and try what @user745229 has suggested at the end.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181822/how-do-i-post-a-javascript-variable-to-an-asp-net-mvc-model)

Answer (score 0):

You could store the Timestamp in a hidden div, then retrieve it and send it via ajax.  Or you can you a databinding framework like knockoutjs or even use signalR to send it back to the server immediately.

Many ways to skin this cat.